# How to print return code conditionally in oh my zsh theme?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to conditionally print return code in custom `oh-my-zsh` theme but somehow I'm failling. I'm stuck with:

```
function get_rc {
rc=$(echo -e "${return_code}" | tr -d '[:space:]' )
[[ "${rc}" == "130" ]] && echo "${rc}" && return
echo "'${rc}'"
}
```

Where it's printing the quouted version all the time.

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Where does `return_code` come from, and why are you explicitly outputting a quoted version when the value if not 130? There seems to be a lot of context missing from this question.

Comment: I added the quotes just to get the understanding when it's returning by one statement/branch versus another. The return code variable was just there in the ad-magic theme so I've used it